# Using VB to retrieve the sum of a column of salaries from an Access database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dataset, oledb

I have been sitting here with five other guys trying out how to total values from a column. We have scoured Google, but none of the code we've found works.

Here is my form:

[image: form]

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
Public Class frmTotal
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim rowindex As Integer = 0
    Dim connstr As String = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;" & "data source=valleyfair.mdb"
    Dim sqlstr As String = "select * from employee"

    Private Sub btnTotal_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnTotal.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub frmTotal_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dt.Clear()
        Dim dataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlstr, connstr)
        dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
        dataAdapter.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either sum in the TSQL or in code.  Here's the TSQL version:

```
select *, SUM(MyColumnName) AS TotalMyColumnName
from employee
```

If you only want the sum then only retrieve the sum and not the other columns

```
select SUM(MyColumnName) AS TotalMyColumnName
from employee
```

Comment: txtTotalSalary.Text = "select *, SUM(employeeSalary) from employee"

Wouldn't that only add select *, SUM(employeeSalary) from employee to the text box?

Comment: your comment has nothing to do with my answer to your question "How to I add a column of salaries " . what you do with the result is up to you

Answer (score 0):

I'm a rookie at SQL but this is one way i imagine it to be done:
1: Declare variables needed.
2: Fetch needed data from database and save it in a database container. The code only gets values in the column salary. (Unsure what you named it but you could just edit it)
3: using a for loop to add all the numbers together.

If you are using oleDB just change whenever it says SQL to OleDB and it should work just the same

```
Dim Result As Integer = 0
Dim salaryDB As New DataTable
Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty
Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

Public Sub GetSum()
    Try
        conn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(Constr) 
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sSQL = "SELECT salary FROM Employee"
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(salaryDB)
        If dtActive.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No record found!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
    For Each Row As DataRow In salaryDB.Rows
        Result = Result + row(0) 'row is the current row selected and 0 is the column number
    Next
End Sub
```